# What are some deep learning models use in timeseries forecasting that include context from covariates?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, neural-networks, forecasting, predictive-models

I was going through the literature for time-series forecasting using DL and all the methods I read about only use the variable of interest at previous timesteps to predict the same variable at time step (t+1). I didn't find any method that includes covariates information in one way or the other except in the Temporal Fusion Transformer.

Can anyone suggest to me some models/articles that include covariates information in deep learning models preferably?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don’t need a special model just enrich the input with exogenous variables should be enough.

Comment: @rapaio do you have an example (notebook or something)? I can't see how to add the other features in a wavenet model for example

Comment: I don’t know about wavelet model, but a simple example, instead of predicting y_t from y_{t-1}, predict y_t from y_{t-1},x_{t-1}. Another setup is to predict y_t,x_t from y_{t-1},x_{t-1}, thus you can do recurring predictions. You simply concatenate sequences

Comment: @rapaio I see thanks. I have a question: let's say x is the region. therefore x_{t-1} = x_{t}=x_{t-2}... in your opinion, should I proceed the same way?

Comment: Yes. A constant is time invariant

Comment: @rapaio Thank  you